# RegEx | Match words with colons but ignore time-like patterns

Tags: javascript, php, regex

For a special function to build better and smarter PDO statements I've matched and extracted every word, which started with a colon.

**PHP like Needle**: `/:\w+/`

But sometimes it also happens that I've to handle strings with colon-seperated digits. (time-values)

- `2018-05-21T00:00:00+02:00`
- `00:00:00`
- `00:00`

I've tried to exclude them, but never succeeded when I tried to extend my regex-needle for this. Because of that issue, I just often workaround this issue. But now I would like to fix and understand how to solve this.

**The condition sounds easy**

1. Find every word, which starts with a colon.
2. Remove every match which has digits before the colon.

So from the current result with `:\w+`:

> `:light` at 07`:15:0000`

I would like just to match:

> `:light` at 07:15:0000

Comment: Is it for PHP or JS or both? Are you extracting or replacing? Try `:[A-Za-z_]\w*` if the first char cannot be a digit.

Comment: `/:[^\d\s]+/` try this

Comment: @bassxzero this matches whitespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those substrings after `:` cannot start with a digit, you may use

```
:[A-Za-z_]\w*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9agsz/3).

Here,

- `:` - a colon
- `[A-Za-z_]` - a letter or `_` (remove `_` if the first char can only be a letter)
- `\w*` - 0+ letters, digits or/and `_`

**Alternatives**

You also may match those time-like strings, and match *and capture* `:\w+`:

```
\d+:\d+(?::\d+)?|(:\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9agsz/1). Only grab Group 1 values if Group 1 matches.

In PHP, you may achieve exactly what you need with a [SKIP-FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) regex:

```
'~\d+:\d+(?::\d+)?(*SKIP)(*F)|:\w+~'
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9agsz/2).

With `(*SKIP)(*F)`, you can match and skip the matches while matching the rest of the alternatives.

Comment: It's just funny that I wasn't able to think about the almost easiest solution like both of you (Wiktor, Andreas) suggested: Using character-ranges instead of word-matching. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `"/:\w+/"` you can use `"/:[a-zA-Z]+/"`that wont capture times.

Comment: It's just funny that I wasn't able to think about the almost easiest solution like both of you (Wiktor, Andreas) suggested: Using character-ranges instead of word-matching. Thank you!